# Finding most common combinations across multiple columns

Tags: r, combinations

I am looking for a most frequent combination of values in my data frame, however, I am not after unique values only. Here is my table:

```
ID <- 1:5
A = c("a", "a", "", "", "a")
B = c("b", "b", "", "", "")
C = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c")
D = c("d", "d", "", "", "d")

df <- data.frame(ID, A, B, C, D, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

and here it what we get:

```
> df
  ID A B C D
1  1 a b c d
2  2 a b c d
3  3     c  
4  4     c  
5  5 a   c d
```

What I am after is this:

```
Comb    Freq
a,b,c,d   2
a,c,d     3
a,c       3
a,d       3
c,d       3
b,c       2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can group by combination and use one of the methods shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9809166/2954547)

Comment: More methods here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18570149/2954547

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table(apply(df[,-1],1, paste ,sep=",", collapse=""))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works to some extent, however, it only counts the occurrence of the whole sequence in the data frame rows, it ignores for example partially matched strings like in my example "a,c", "a,d" etc. I am aware of other solutions but they do not answer my question completely.